# Get the response of csv file in network section

Tags: csv, cakephp

I'd like to get the response of a CSV file that I am exporting from pages. So basically what it does now is that it downloads a CSV file but what I'd like here is to read the CSV file here :

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIDYJ.png]

here is what is displayed on firefox (I'd like the same in google chrome):
[image]

And here is the code for the export :

```
public function export()
    {
        $this->response = $this->response->withDownload('Cultures.csv');
        $Cultures = $this->ConstCultures->find();
        $_serialize = 'Cultures';
        $_header = ['code', 'libelle'];
        $_extract = [
            'code', 'libelle'
        ];
        $_bom = true;

        $this->viewBuilder()->setClassName('CsvView.Csv');
        $this->set(compact('Cultures', '_serialize', '_header', '_extract', '_bom'));
    }
```

Edit : it works on firefox and edge but in chrome I have this warning "Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type text/csv"

Comment: "I'd like to get the response of a CSV" what response you want to get?

Comment: @Sehdev i've edited the post

Comment: Not clear from the documentation whether you might need to `return $this->response` at the end of this function to have your changes recognized. Should be an easy thing for you to test.